NextJS Middleware matcher
I have a NextJS middleware where I need to check if a category exists. If not, go to a 404 page.
The directory looks like this
pages/
├──[category_code].jsx
└── ...(other pages)
middleware.jsx

The middleware is being executed but how do I match this path in the matcher config?
Here's my middlware
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(request) {
    // this is executed
}

// I need this middleware to target [category_code].jsx
export const config = {
    matcher: "/pages/:path",
};

I need this middleware to target [category_code].jsx but it doesn't.
Ive tried
/:path
/:path*
/:category_code
/[category_code]

What should I do?

You could try handling the path individually within the middleware. The matcher can simply be set to the default matcher for everything except API routes and static assets. This will provide more flexibility in handling other path instances. Here's an example of how to do this:

    export default async function middleware(request, response) {
      const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;
    
      // Check if the path is a category
      if (!pathname.matches('[category_code]')) {
        // throw error or redirect
        return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Category Not Found' }, { status: 404 });
      }


      // handle other routes
    }
    
    export const config = {
      matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)'],
    };



The "pathname" value is actually the path parameter rather than [category_code]. So this doesn't work.

Sorry i might misunderstanding the issue, so using the next url comes in and checking it won't work?

No, basically there is no way to get the path structure. For example, my file name is [category_code].js, so it takes in a category code. The 'pathname' is the actual category_code and not '[category_code]'
